# AWS Elastic BeanStalk Docker root file system switch to read-only

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I use a docker application running on beanstalk for autoscaling.

The / file system within docker switch itself to read only at random times.

The application is generating a lot of logs but they are written to a dedicated volume and this one doesn't have the issue.

I tried to issue `mount -o remount,rw /` within the container, but I get "permission denied"

Answer (score 5):

This happened to us twice recently, within about 48 hours.  Both times we 'fixed' the problem by redeploying the docker image to Elastic Beanstalk.  During the second redeploy EBS moved our app onto a new EC2 instance.  The problem hasn't recurred since (it's been a couple of weeks).

Our theory is that the error was being caused by a failing disk.  The kernel can remount a file system as read-only if corruption is detected.  (This also might fit with the error you saw trying to remount the file system as read-write?).  Since we've been moved onto new hardware we no longer have access to the old EC2 instance to investigate further.

Leaving this comment here in case this happens to someone else and they can continue the investigation.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue with ElasticBeanstalk when we were using a heavy IO consuming application. The problem did not get recreated when we using the same application in an EC2 instance.

And then moving to ElasticContainerService resolved the issue for us.

Comment: We ran into this issue on AWS/ECS/EBS multi-container. Our container was writing a lot of logs (JBoss). The solution was to add a Docker volume (not bind volume) to Dockerrun.aws for the container file-system. We also disabled logs to disk, since it's going to stdout/CloudWatch.